# Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'session:didReceiveMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error e copied the code directly from Apple. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:': 'void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(NSDictionary * _Nonnull __strong)' vs 'void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(NSDictionary * _Nonnull __strong)'

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary * __nonnull))replyHandler {
```

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: I havent been able to figure it out. It must be something simple. For now I have left the warning message there and everything seems to work ok

Comment: ok thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

As the message states, there is a conflict on the signature of the method. Look in the header file that the method is in and cut and paste the appropriate header (remember to remove the semi colon)

Comment: OK as I stated I tried everything. What exactly would you enter?

Comment: - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message
{ }